# How to create a new sequence starting with the value of another sequence in hsql?

Tags: sequence, hsqldb

Database is HSQLDB.
I have an existing sequence, say SEQ1.
Now I want create another sequence SEQ2 that starts with the next value of SEQ1.

I tried

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ2 START WITH SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ1;
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ2 START WITH (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ1);
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ2 START WITH NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ1;
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ2 START WITH (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ1);
```

None of these seem to work however. Is there another way to achieve this in HSQLDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. Only a numeric literal can be used after `START WITH` or after `ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH`.